# Do everywhere discontinuous functions like these one described exist?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, continuity

These are the properties that such functions should (could?) have:

1) $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$

2) $f$ is everywhere discontinuous

3) $\mathbb Q \subseteq f( \mathbb I)$

4) $f(\mathbb Q) \subset \mathbb I$

That is, such functions should (could?) have all these properties simultaneously: They map the whole $\mathbb R$ onto the whole $\mathbb R$, they are everywhere discontinuous, they map the set of all irrational numbers $\mathbb I$ into some set that contains all rationals, and they map the set of all rationals into some subset of the set of all irrationals.

Remark: This is not a homework, I am just eager into doing research of everywhere discontinuous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g : \mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{R}$ be onto (such a function exists because $\mathbb{I}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality), and partition $\mathbb{Q}$ into two disjoint dense sets $Q_1, Q_2$.  Then let
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x), & x \in \mathbb{I} \\
-\sqrt{2}, & x \in Q_1 \\
\sqrt{2}, & x \in Q_2.\end{cases}$$

Comment: $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ should be "everywhere close to each other", right?

Comment: @YamMir: Yes, that is accomplished by having them both be dense.  For instance, you may take $Q_1$ to be the set of dyadic rationals $n/2^k$, and $Q_2 = \mathbb{Q} \setminus Q_1$.

Comment: Do you know of some concrete constructed example of such $g$ which is from $\mathbb I$ onto $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @YamMir: Pick your favorite countable set of irrationals, $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dots\}$, and enumerate the rationals as $\{q_1, q_2, \dots\}$.  If $n$ is even, let $g(a_n) = a_{n/2}$.  If $n$ is odd, let $g(a_n) = q_{(n+1)/2}$.  If $x \in \mathbb{I} \setminus A$, let $g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+\sqrt 2&\text{if }x=a+b\sqrt 2\text{ with }a\in\Bbb Q, b\in\Bbb Z\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

Comment: But if $r$ is rational and not of the form $r=a+b\sqrt 2$ then $f(r)=r$ so $f(\mathbb Q) \cap \mathbb I  \nsubseteq \mathbb I$, so $0$ is a problem?

Comment: I think I misunderstood something, I will think about your example again.

Comment: But all the irrationals which are not of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ are mapped into themselves, how can then $\mathbb Q \subseteq f( \mathbb I)$ be true?  What do I miss?